# Possible to print a List<> of DTOs to console?

Tags: c#, list, dto

I'm trying to print a list of DTO objects to a Console statement. I am grabbing a list of objects by category name (PK) from SQL server and converting them to DTO's to pass to the client. I should elaborate... Each object (in the object table) has a category along with some other strings, the Category table's PK is 'CategoryName'

Here is an example of my code:

```
foreach(Object ii in context.Objects.Where(i => i.Commodity.CategoryName == categoryName)) 
{
                ObjectDTO objectDTO = EncodeDTO.BuildObjectDTO(ii);
                lotDTOList.Add(ii);
}
```

I tried using:

```
//for testing
objectDTOList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
return objectDTOList;
```

Comment: What you have should work - as long as ObjectDTO.ToString() actually outputs something.

Comment: I thought it would also, it turns out though it doesn't return anything meaningful (for me). Although it does print out something:

"namespace.models.EF.object"

I tried changing my test message to basically what Eric J. posted and it returned something meaningful enough for me to where I feel confident that my code is working as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
list.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
```

Remember to override ToString() to get meaningful output, or alternatively do something like:

```
list.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.SomeMeaningfulProperty));
```